# How to rectify the sign up amazon-codewhispere extension

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, visual-studio-code, jupyter, amazon-codewhisperer

In visual studio code I install AWS extension I sign up amazon-codewhisperer but it does not work..For past one week I sign up the Extension it always show it's not you it's us..try again later.any one help for me to  rectify my problem.

[image: How to sign up AWS IN Visual studio CODE]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.